# solana logs failing with: Error: unable to connect to server yet solana-test-validator is running

Tags: solana, solana-cli

I am trying to run the `solana logs` command to see the logs.
But upon running this, it fails and doesn't connect to the localhost server. see below output:
[image]

As you will see from the screenshot above, I already have the `solana-test-validator` running.
But `solana logs --url localhost` ain't working or is unable to connect to the server

Answer (score 1):

The solution in my case is the url specification, 
kindly note that in this case, localhost translates to 127.0.0.1 but still in my case, I still needed to even specify the port:
Thus instead of using localhost, I used:

```
solana logs --url http://127.0.0.1:8899
```